# Center text inside rect using Highcharts Drawing API

Tags: text, highcharts, drawing, center

I tried using the drawing API of highcharts. Im trying to create a custom map with text inside. But I cant find a way to center the text inside a rect. I have to create a uniform width boxes with varying text inside. Is there any way to center the text inside with manually adjusting/adding 
 just like the example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer. Thanks.

Comment: Please paste the code you have tried.

Comment: ren.label('Example Long Text)', 5, 50)
   .attr({
    padding: 10,
    width: 50,
    zIndex: 5,
    r: 5
    })
.css({
  color: 'white'
  })
  .add()
  .shadow(true);
      
ren.rect(10, 10, 100, 100, 5)
.attr({
'stroke-width': 2,
 fill: colors[0],
 zIndex: 3})
.add();
}}

Comment: Please add the code with the question so it is easier for people  trying to help you when looking at the question on SO.

Comment: Well I only used the example provide by http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer. The text there was manually adjusted using line break <br/>. Is there any method to center text inside a container created uding highcharts drawing? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can center text inside a container with attribute text-anchor like this

```
renderer.text('helloworld', xVal, yVal).attr({
    "text-anchor" : "middle"
}).add();
```

Answer (score 0):

The elemens are printed as SVG / VML elements, not HTML, so you cannot use text-align:center;

Answer (score 0):

Have found the solution for aligning the text in center

ren.label('   TEST',210, 200 ,'rect', null, null, true)

Label comes useHTML parameter which is set to false by default.
You can use  the pre tag also.